# Floating point exception (core dumped).In creator random numbers

Tags: c, random

I am trying to create a program to give random numbers in the range between 0 and 0,3. And with give by user seed. My code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int getrand(int min,int max);
int main()
{
 unsigned seed;

 int p=0, i=0;
 float min,max;
 printf("Input a random number seed: ");
 scanf("%u",&seed);
 srand(seed);

  for(i=0;i<getrand(0,0.3); i++) p=getrand(min,max);

printf("Random value : %d \n",p);


 return(0);
}
int getrand(int min,int max){
    return(rand()%(max-min)+min);
}

and
```

When i run it it give me this error: Floating point exception (core dumped)
I can found the error.

Comment: The definition of your `getrand` function specifies two integer arguments.  `0.3` ain't no integer.  I'm a little surprised that caused a core dump, but I'd fix it anyway.

Comment: Ditto with the other call - you are passing two floats in that case (`getrand(min,max)`). Perhaps compile with all the warnings on

Comment: What is "I can found the error" supposed to mean? That you can't find the error? Assuming so, you could rewrite that as "I can't find the error". I'd do the edit for you but I wasn't sure what you meant and didn't want to misunderstand. The alternative could be that you can find the error which could be written more like: "I found the error".

Answer (score 2):

`getrand(0,0.3)` convert 0.3 to `int` --> `getrand(0,0)` --> `rand()%(0-0)` --> division by 0.  This is often reported as a "Floating point exception "

Instead `1.0*rand()/RAND_MAX * 0.3`

---

There are other numeric issues that affect the quality of the random numbers produces, yet the above will handle OP's FPE and range issues

Comment: You might as well delete the comment!